# IOS Simulator quit unexpectedly Xcode 10.1

Tags: ios, xcode, appium, simulator

After running automation tests via Appium in parallel (8 concurrent IOS simulators) I can't run simulator anymore. Reason still is not clear. I tried to reinstall Xcode (v10.1 v9.4), recovered Mac OS, used  `killall -10 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService` . When I run simulator there it error message:

> Simulator quit unexpectedly

```
Process:               Simulator [1439]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator
Identifier:            com.apple.iphonesimulator
Version:               10.1 (877)
Build Info:            Indigo-877000000000000~218
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Simulator [1439]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2019-01-12 16:19:15.922 +0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.2 (18C54)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     3.3 (16P53132a)
Anonymous UUID:        746485C4-4AA2-44F7-C299-5A58EB4FD0C5


Time Awake Since Boot: 170 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        7  Dispatch queue: com.apple.iphonesimulator.deviceCoordinatorQueue.457B5DF1-903C-41E0-A9B7-42D97AC96569

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes:       KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x000070000b351fe8
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Bus error: 10
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xa
Terminating Process:   exc handler [1439]

VM Regions Near 0x70000b351fe8:
    Stack                  000070000b2cf000-000070000b351000 [  520K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  thread 6
--> STACK GUARD            000070000b351000-000070000b352000 [    4K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  stack guard for thread 7
    Stack                  000070000b352000-000070000b3d4000 [  520K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  thread 7
```

Interesting point: when I run Appium test there is still the same error but test is passed as it looks like Simulator still works in headless.

Approximately same issue I have found there but it is a little bit different https://shirome9.wordpress.com/2016/11/27/xcode-quit-unexpectedly/

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the real cause of the issue, but I got resolved by restarting and opening with different simulator.